# How can i add image on center of status bar in android

Tags: android

I am developing on app i am stuck at point add image on status bar. When app is foreground then add image into notification bar otherwise image is no visible. Please any one help me. I am attaching what i want. Thanks advance. Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom view on ActionBar.

```
// inflate the view with your image
View view = ...

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(view)
```

`getActionView()` is a method of `Activity`, so if you're calling from a fragment, use `getActivity().getActionBar()`.